# Open iframe in Firefox Firebug extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I am writing Firefox extension which add one custom tab in Firebug. I want open iframe in my tab, how can I do it? Now loads mainOverlay.xul

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<overlay xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script type="application/x-javascript" src="mainOverlay.js"/>
</overlay>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do with overlay but you can just create and insert the iframe on runtime, when you detect your tab click.

This gist shows how to add iframe, you must use html namespace otherwise it won't fire load events.
https://gist.github.com/yajd/9476471

Then appendChild into your tab in Firebug.